# How to suppress sub report section based on main report field in Crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I want to suppress sub report section based on main report field value.

How to do it in Crystal report?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: pass the main report value to sub report and write supress conition for the section need to be supressed. if this is not sufficeint then show your efforts and tell where are you struck.

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure for hiding a sub report which runs:

1. Suppress all sections in the sub report.  Even if a section only contains white space, it must be suppressed.
2. Right-click on the sub report object in the main report and select “Format Subreport…”. This will open the Format Editor.
3. Select the “Subreport” tab in the Format Editor.
4. place a check mark in the “Suppress Blank Subreport” check box.
5. If you have placed the sub report in its own section, you can now suppress the section by setting the “Suppress Blank Section” in the Section Expert.